# deleting a row in a table

Tags: mysql, asp.net, vb.net

I have a following markup on my web page:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView" runat="server" 
      AutoGenerateDeleteButton="True"
<Columns>
     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID" Visible="false"> 
           <ItemTemplate>
              <asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server" Text='<% #Eval("ID")%>'></asp:Label>
           </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>
...
```

I am trying to get the value of the text field to get the correct ID of the row that I want to be deleted, however I do not know how to exactly do it, I have tried following code:

```
Protected Sub GridView_RowDeleting(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewDeleteEventArgs) Handles GridView.RowDeleting
    Dim row As GridViewRow = GridView.Rows(e.RowIndex)
    Dim ID As Integer = TryCast(row.FindControl("lblID"), TextBox).Text
...
```

However after clicking on the delete button on the generated web page I just get error:

> "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Visual Studio points the error to the "TryCast".
I can not find any similar examples and do not understand what is happening, if somebody has a better idea of getting that ID value that would also work?

Comment: This bit of code is absolutely wrong: `TryCast(row.FindControl("lblID"), TextBox).Text`. The whole point of using `TryCast` is that it might fail and you might get `Nothing`, so accessing a member of the result directly is just wrong. If you know the cast will succeed and it is safe to access a member like that then you should be using `DirectCast`, otherwise you should be testing the result of `TryCast` first and only using it if it's not `Nothing`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `lblID` control certainly is a label defined by this control markup:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server" Text='<% #Eval("ID")%>'></asp:Label>
```

On this line you tried to cast the label control as `TextBox` instead of `Label`, so it returns `Nothing` and throwing `NullReferenceException` when accessing `Text` property:

```
Dim ID As Integer = TryCast(row.FindControl("lblID"), TextBox).Text
```

What do you need is cast to `Label` and get `Text` property there:

```
Dim ID As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(TryCast(row.FindControl("lblID"), Label).Text)
```

Note that `Convert.ToInt32` added because `Text` property of a label control contains string value, hence casting to `Integer` is necessary. If you're not sure it will return `Nothing`, use `Integer.TryParse` instead.

Comment: Thank you very much for this, I just did not see it.